# Let f_n: [0, 1] -> R - continuous function and serie sum(f_n(x), n from 0 to +infinity) converge for all x from [0, 1].

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Prove that exist some piece [a, b] in [0, 1] such that a!=b and exist C such that for all x in [a, b], for all natural n is true that |sum(f_i(x), i from 0 to n)| < C.

I know that f_i is limited and sum(f_i) can be not continuous, but what I can do next?

Comment: Hi! Edit your post with MathJax so it is easier to undertand what you are asking! If you want help about how to do that you can use this tutorial:  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: You should at least complete your sentences if you want to receive an answer.

Comment: Sorry, I did not see.